# Blazor Two Way Binding <select>/<option>

Tags: html, razor, blazor

Running into issues trying to update list options in a select. When `Function One` button is clicked, it fires `functionTwo` which returns a new list, that should now be the updated list shown in the `<select>/<option>`

Can someone educate me on what I am not getting correct?

```html
 <button ... @onclick="functionOne">Function One</button>

<select @bind="@SelectedValue">
    @foreach (var val in updatedList)
    {
        <option value="@val">@val</option>
    }
</select>

  public void functionOne()
 {
    ... 
    List<string> updatedList ...
    updatedList = functionTwo();
    ...
 }

  public List<string> functionTwo()
 {
    ...
       
    return strList ;
 }
```

Comment: Can you try calling `StateHasChanged()` after calling `functionTwo`, but I doubt that will be the solution. Also I tried the same thing in my sample app and it works fine without issue.

Comment: Really!? why does my bug out..hmmm must me other logic that is causing it to fail. No change calling that function

Comment: Too many `...` . You cannot bind to the local var `updatedList`. Create a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by this @HenkHolterman?

Comment: Your code is incomplete and inconsistent. Click that link to see what is expected on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this into index.razor of blazor see if it works

```cs
@page "/"

<p>@SelectedValue</p>

<button @onclick="functionOne">Function One</button>

<select @bind="@SelectedValue">
    @foreach (var val in updatedList)
    {
        <option value="@val">@val</option>
    }
</select>

@code
{
    string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    List<string> updatedList = new List<string>();

    private void functionOne()
    {

        updatedList = functionTwo();
    }

    public List<string> functionTwo()
    {
        return new List<string> { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" };
    }
}
```

Comment: did this help you?

Comment: Hey Nathan, sorry just getting a chance to review this. this didn't help, but thank you for the effort.

Comment: So i had some time to look at this yesterday, the code yours and mine was fine. What was taking place was the bound list was getting appended to, and not replaced so it was giving the appearance of not being updated. Simply updating the instance of the list was all that was needed.Thanks for your help! Take care Nathan!